# RDP from Windows 8 to older Windows

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

My problem is simple. From my computer (Windows 8 Entreprise N), i want to manage some servers (Windows 2003 and Windows 2008).

I use Windows+R and Windows+E everytime.

Since i change my computer to Windows 8, Windows+ shortcuts are executed on local computer not on the remote computer, even if in mstsc.exe options is set "on remote computer".

I found lot of "new Windows shortcuts", but i want to use existing shortcuts which was working from Windows 7.

PS:
- I never encounter this problem with Windows 7
- I always run RDP in fullscreen
- My windows 7 and Windows 8 run on dual screen (same behavior with one screen)
- The "Windows Key" is executed on both remote (open start menu) and local computer (open metro)

Thank you

Comment: Alternatives ammyy admin, real vnc

Comment: Yes but i need some features like copy/paste, printing and mapping drive.

Comment: Off-topic, but someone else started it.  Recommend using RoyalTS.  Loyal customer for years (there's a free version too).  Can definitely map the Windows key to the remote PC.

Comment: Hi. This is an older reply of a similar problem someone had: http://www.windows-server-answers.com/microsoft/Windows-Terminal-Services/29224857/shift-not-workingvista-remote-desktop-client.aspx

Comment: I have tested RoytalTS. But I have the same problem. Windows+R, Windows+E, Ctrl+Shift+Escape are executed on local machine, not in remote machine, even if I check "Windows Key passthrough".

Comment: Found !! I need the uninstall KB2973201, this bug affect RDP and MKS (vmware) https://communities.vmware.com/message/2403040

Comment: If you found a solution that works for you, feel free to post it here as an answer, including all details that make it work for you.

Comment: I found 2 problems on my Windows 8 : one using RDP, one using MKS (vmware remote console). Someone says on VMware forum "uninstall 6 KB installed the day when the bug appear". I uninstall one (KB2973201), i choose this one because of this name "visual keyboard", and restart... After i add this KB into ingore list. Nothing more :)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to reproduce this by connecting to a Win7 and Win2k8R2 machine from a Win8.1 box. I have verified that the update you mentioned above is installed on all machines via this cmdlet

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_quickfixengineering | ? {$_.HotfixId -eq 'KB2973201'}
```

This is not reproducible if I set to remote the keyboard always and this sessions has the focus the keystrokes only go to the remote session. If I set it to only forward these if the session is full screen then it will go to my local Win8.1 machine unless the session is full screen.

You may want to ask on the Impero support line, sorry I cannot be of more help

Comment: These are horrible answers.  Why are there two of them though?

Comment: Bob, this is not how this site works, this is not a fourm, your first answer should have been a comment, not an answer, your 2nd answer should have been a edit to your first answer.

Comment: As mentioned this is not a forum but a Question and Answer site.  While we appreciate a Microsoft employee weighing in on the issue it may help if you take a look at the [tour](http://superuser.com/tour) to see how we differ from a conventional forum.  Welcome to Super User!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes though you can he comment when as a new user his rep is so low?

Comment: @barlop Getting a total of 5 upvotes ([only 50 rep is required to comment](http://superuser.com/help/privileges)) is not hard to acheive. Take the effort to answer a few questions that you don't need to comment on for clarification and get your 50 points.